# Site producing bad urls?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-search-console, genesis

I'm using a custom Genesis child theme and lately I've been noticing that many false articles have been showing up on webmaster tools. They look something like this:

[image]

I haven't written these nor are they topics my site focuses on so I have no clue why they are showing up. So far, I've had to delete about a hundred of these. I read on a forum that this can be due to my theme generating bad urls but I'm not sure what that means nor do I know how to fix it. What can be causing this?

Comment: These are 404 pages. The Urls in question do not exis. Anybody can call lots of arbitrary urls on your server (they are not produced by our CMS but by the person or script calling them - Webmaster Tools do not report on your CMS).  It's when an unknown Url produces a valid response that you should start to worry.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks, that eases my concerns. But what could be causing them to show up all of a sudden? I recently did a redesign and they started showing up shortly after.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this problem is due to your website being hacked or Google is trying to Crawl or follow a link within your content that is not really a link.

This is what webmaster tool tells you about the problem:

> > *In Crawl Errors, you might occasionally see 404 errors for URLs you don't believe exist on your own site or on the web. These unexpected URLs might be generated by Googlebot trying to follow links found in JavaScript, Flash files, or other embedded content.*

To find out if your website has been hacked. First get this total = WordPress number of pages + number of post + number of categories + number of PDF or files + Images. Then do a google search using the following query (without the quotes) "**site:yourdomain.com**" if the result number is exaggerated greater than the calculated total then your website is definitely hacked.

If you believe that your website is not hacked try to find from where these links are being generated. Here is the trick: Go to the Web Master Tool report and click on one of those links, check the "Linked from" tab. There should be one or many possible **pages listed** from where these unexpected links are coming from.

Two possible Outcomes:

1. The page from where the link is found is from your own website: Go
   to that page and open the source code, do a Ctrl+F search for that
   link, if found check what section or content is generating this
   problem.
2. The page from where the link is found is NOT from your own website:
   In this case try to contact the owner of the other site and ask the
   link to be removed, if not possible I highly recommend you to create
   a 404 page within your WordPress installation with some useful
   links. Google how to do this, there are plenty of resources.

Hope this helps

Comment: I checked each of your points and everything looks fine. Also, there aren't any suspicious files. However, I googled the links from the image in my post and [both led me to this site](http://www.sportpulse.net/content/icc-world-cup-2015-ind-v-uae-clinical-india-thrash-uae-9-wickets-160721). Also, upon further googling, I found [this site](http://sports.alltop.com/?keepThis=trueTB_iframe=true) which seems to be an aggregation of sports news from various sites, and both my site and "Sportpulse" are included. What is going on here? Why are Sportpulse articles being shown in my Webmasters tools?

Comment: Might I ask you which Webmaster tool report are you looking at?

Comment: I'm using Google Webmasters Tools.

Comment: Ok, you are looking to the Google Webmaster Tool crawl error (URL error section) report. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @J82 I was reviewing my answers and found that this was not marked as completed. If this answered (or helped to answer) your concern, could you please mark it as the solution?